# AG Grid - Always/Conditionally show chevron icon

Tags: ag-grid

Instead of getting all the data once in client side model. I want to fetch group data on row expand event.

I have implemented `onRowGroupOpened` event and on I am able to send query to backend on the event, get response and merge it with previous response and redraw the grid.

But the problem is that if the row doesn't have child initially, it won't show the chevron icon to be clicked on.

Is there a way to always show the icon in front of a row?